# What is the difference between reading a file with >> operator and reading a file with read function?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream obj;
    obj.open("a.txt");
    char i;
    obj.read((char *)&i, 1);
    cout << i;
    obj.close();

    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between reading a file with >> operator and with the read function in c++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) function reads a given number of characters, while [`operator>>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) reads with formatting and data interpretation.

For example:

```
char buf[11];
cin.read(buf, 10);
buf[10] = 0;
int a;
cin >> a;
```

With the given input `12345678901234567890`, the result is

```
strcmp(buf, "1234567890") == 0
a == 1234567890
```

Comment: No, I did not :)